# INTEL UNDI PXE MESSAGE AT BOOT TIME- LENOVO LAPTOP

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot, fedora, lenovo-laptop

I have Lenovo G580 laptop. I have installed two operating systems, namely, Windows 7 and Fedora 20. When my laptop boots it shows a message as "Intel UNDI PXE-2.0 (build 083) and blah blah...".
I searched for the similar problem on Internet and they told to reorder my boot order. I did reorder my boot order as follow:
1. HDD
2. CD
3. Windows Boot Manager
4. ubuntu
5. PCI LAN

But surprisingly the boot order automatically changes when I reboot my laptop after saving the changes I made. Also `ubuntu` is not installed on my laptop currently. I had installed it previously but then removed it, completely formatted whole disk and installed Windows first and then on it installed Fedora. I don't understand still why this Intel UNDI message appears. Is it something related to "phantom" ubuntu entry that appears in the boot order? Please help me.

Comment: What exactly is "blah blah"?

Comment: What exactly is the *problem* here? Perhaps that is the BIOS start-up message, and can not be removed.

Answer (score 1):

The presenting issue you are having has nothing to do with Ubuntu - your system is trying to network boot off the chip on the network card.

I wonder if you are correctly saving your drive boot order - if you are, then you may want to see if you can flash your BIOS, otherwise take your motherboard/system back to your provider to solve as its not working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

you can define a boot order in your bios that i.e. includes your HDD as the first booting option "but" if your HDD is not "bootable" (OS not installed, OS damaged, MBR damaged, etc) then the BIOS will try other options from the booting list. This list many times has by default booting from the "net" as the last option. When booting from the NET fails you see that UNDI message you get.